# Allow Azure services to connect to Azure SQL Server by API

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

If you create SQL Server by Azure Management Portal, it is possible to allow Azure services to connect by a switch in Configure panel on a server page. I want to do that by requesting Service Management API. Is it possible?

I searched in [Operations for Azure SQL Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505719.aspx) and [Azure SQL Database REST API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163571.aspx).

Update: code block with example

```
internal string CreateFirewallRule(string serverName)
{
    var firewallParameters = new FirewallRuleCreateParameters();
    firewallParameters.Name = "AllowAll";
    firewallParameters.StartIPAddress = "0.0.0.0";
    firewallParameters.EndIPAddress = "0.0.0.0";
    var response = _sqlMgmtClient.FirewallRules.Create(serverName, firewallParameters);
    return response.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow other Azure Services to connect to your Azure SQL Database Server, you will need to set firewalls accordingly. In [Portal.Azure.com](https://Portal.Azure.com), if you go to the server, then settings and select Firewall Rules you can enable other Azure services to connect to the server. This will set up a firewall rule for the range 0.0.0.0 to 0.0.0.0.

If you would like to do this via REST APIs you can use the [Create Firewall Rule API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505712.aspx). You will need to specify the range of 0.0.0.0 to 0.0.0.0 to allow other Azure Services to connect to the server. You can also use Azure PowerShell to do this with [New Firewall Rule cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn546724.aspx).

Update: code block with example

```
internal string CreateFirewallRule(string serverName)
{
    var firewallParameters = new FirewallRuleCreateParameters();
    firewallParameters.Name = "AllowAll";
    firewallParameters.StartIPAddress = "0.0.0.0";
    firewallParameters.EndIPAddress = "0.0.0.0";
    var response = _sqlMgmtClient.FirewallRules.Create(serverName, firewallParameters);
    return response.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This really helped. Added code example inside question because can't do it in a comment in acceptable form. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear this unblocked you. Let's add the working example to the answer to help improve visibility for others who come across this issue. :-)